# how can i plot data from a mat file after using uigetfile (MATLAB)

Tags: user-interface, mat

i'm building a gui on Matlab and i want to plot data from a .mat file which contains 5 rows and 5 columns. I want to plot each five rows in 5 different axis. For example the first row of the file is a rf pulse sequence and i want to plot it in the rf_axis i've made.The second is the gx pulse sequence and i want to plot it on another axis. I use uigetfile to browse the mat file but i cannot plot the data from the file. Here is the code

```
filename = uigetfile('*.mat')
pathname='/home/anastasia/Documents/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/projects/ptuxiaki';
loaddata = fullfile(pathname,filename)
dat=load(loaddata)
time_step=str2double(get(handles.time_step_EDIT,'String'));
t=0:time_step:6.4-time_step;
X1=dat(1,:);
plot(handles.RFs_axis,t,X1)
zoom on
X2=dat(2,:);
plot(handles.RFa_axis,t,X2)
zoom on
X3=dat(3,:);
plot(handles.Gx_axis,t,X3);
zoom on
X4=dat(4,:);
plot(handles.Gy_axis,t,X4);
zoom on
X5=dat(5,:);
plot(handles.Gz_axis,t,X5);
zoom on
```

Comment: Check out the subplot command

Comment: it doesn't work because the variable dat is a struct 1x1 and it is not the data i want because i want to plot something like 1x5 double